# How can I retrieve my environment variables in a parameter file in Symfony4 structure?

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables, symfony4, symfony-flex

I did a fresh Symfony installation by using Symfony Flex and the new skeleton belong to the next Symfony 4 directory structure.

I add and configure a first third-party bundle : [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle). This bundle is used to connect via Twitter using two secret information.

I declare my `consumer_id` and my `consumer_secret` in the `config/packages/hwi_oauth.yaml` file.

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_names: [secured_area]
    resource_owners:
        twitter:
            type:          twitter
            client_id:     XXXXXMyIdXXXXX
            client_secret: XXXXXMyTopSecretKeyXXXXX
```

**My application works fine. But I cannot commit my secrets on github!**

I want to have a `hwi_oauth.yaml` file like this one:

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_names: [secured_area]
    resource_owners:
        twitter:
            type:          twitter
            client_id:     '%twitter_consumer_id%'
            client_secret: '%twitter_consumer_secret%'
```

I read the [Symfony4 best practices](http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-best-practices.html) about the new DotEnv package.

> Using environment variables, while far from being perfect, have many benefits over what we currently do. Environment variables are a more "standard" way of managing settings that depend on the environment (no need to manage a parameters.yml.dist for instance).

As suggested in best practices, I append these two line to `.env` file:

```
TWITTER_CONSUMER_ID=XXXXXMyIdXXXXX
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET=XXXXXMyTopSecretKeyXXXXX
```

But I encountered this error:

> You have requested a non-existent parameter "twitter_consumer_id".

I tried with `%kernel.twitter_consumer_id%` , `%env.twitter_consumer_id%` , `%env(TWITTER_CONSUMER_ID)%` with no more success.

The last test is returning this error message:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Environment variable not found: "TWITTER_CONSUMER_ID".").

**How can I retrieve my ENV variables in a parameter file like `hwi_oauth.yaml`?**

Comment: Are you loading the `.env` with the `DotEnv` component?

Comment: Thanks @bishop ! The `public\index.php` contains `if (!getenv('APP_ENV')) { (new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env'); }` and this `.env` was not loaded. It works now ! But the check is to ensure we don't use `.env` in production. I don't understand how to use it in dev and still protect my prod... Is it secured to repace the test `!getenv('APP_ENV')` by this one: `in_array(getenv('APP_ENV'), ['dev','test'])` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to load the `.env` file during your bootstrap process, in order for those environment variables to be available:

```
(new DotEnv())->load(__DIR__ . '/../.env');
```

You should plan to put secret keys in environment variables on development, staging, and production. *How you do that depends, though.* In development and staging, perhaps you use `.env` files, while on production you use Apache to inject.

Personally, I always use `.env` files, and I keep a blank one in my repository. That way it's super simple to deploy, and there aren't any special cases.

If you only want to use `.env` files in specific environments, you can do:

```
if (in_array(getenv('APP_ENV'), [ 'dev', 'test' ])) {
    (new DotEnv())->load(__DIR__ . '/../.env');
}
```

Comment: +1 Even though `getenv('APP_ENV')` will require to set `APP_ENV` env var in your local dev machine. I'd suggest add the default one too `if (!getenv('APP_ENV') || ...)`.

Comment: Indeed, @yceruto. One having to set an environment variable to load environment variables. O_o Part of the reason I unconditionally use env files.

Comment: @bishop it means we need to set an environment variable (`APP_ENV`) to be able to load the `.env` file? This is what @yceruto is warning I think :/

Answer (score 5):

For `test` environments I'd suggest also create a `bootstrap.php` script to override the `.env` parameters:

tests/bootstrap.php:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv;

require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$dotEnv = new Dotenv();
$dotEnv->load(__DIR__.'/../.env');
$dotEnv->populate([
    'APP_ENV' => 'test',
    'DATABASE_URL' => '...'
    // ...
]);
```

phpunit.xml.dist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php" <--- set
         ...
>
    ...
</phpunit>
```