# Test and Dev Enviroment on same machine in Symfony Flex / Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-flex

**Can I put my databse configuration in a configuration file in config/packages/test/ somehow?**

I want to run my tests on my development PC and do the dev work in parallel.
In Symfony 3 I had 2 configurations files

> config_test.yaml and config_dev.yaml

where I could put in 2 different database connections.
Now the database connection is in the *.env* File, so I can not have 2 of them.

I also need to run my fixtures and database helpers and the 2 databases (dev and test) seperatly:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=dev
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction --env=dev
```

Comment: Could this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45889375/4224384 help you ?

Comment: thanks, but I can not run the console commands than

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to remove the databse connection from the .env file and move it into seperated config files again:

config/packages/**dev**/doctrine.yaml:

```
parameters:
    DATABASE_URL: 'mysql://root@localhost:3306/database'
```

and
config/packages/**test**/doctrine.yaml:

```
parameters:
    DATABASE_URL: 'mysql://root@localhost:3306/database_test'
```

and inthe main doctrine configuration file config/packages/doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%DATABASE_URL%'
```

also in phpunit.xml.dist:

```
<env name="DATABASE_URL" value="mysql://root@localhost:3306/database_test" />
```

Now you can have your test and dev environment on the same system and your databse is not polluted by testing data and you can update your databases with:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=dev
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=test
```